# Why when reloading Kendo UI GRID page from browser url, all of data do not display and just display grid without data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

when i reload the kendo grid page,the Information is lost and you have to stop the program and restart it!? where is my problem and how to fix it?

this is my view of kendo ui grid in ASP.NET MVC 5:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
@using UserManagerSample.ViewModels;
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI


<script 
src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js">
```

```
     @(Html.Kendo(). Grid<UserViewModel>() .Name("grid")
     .Columns(columns =>
      {
      columns.Bound(p =>
      p.UserName);

    columns.Bound(p => p.password);
    columns.Bound(p => p.ConfirmPassword);
    columns.Bound(p => 
     p.Fakerole).ClientTemplate("#=Fakerole.FakeRoleName#")
  .Title("Role").EditorTemp 
  lateName("FakeRoleDropDownList").Width(180);

     columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(150);
   })
   .ToolBar(toolBar =>
    {
    toolBar.Create();
    toolBar.Save();
})
 .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.ClientDetailTemplateId("Test")
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.UserId);

        model.Field(p => p.UserId).Editable(false);
        model.Field(e => e.password);
        model.Field(e => e.ConfirmPassword);
        model.Field(p => p.Fakerole).DefaultValue(
        ViewData["defaultCategory"] as FakeRoleViewModel);
    })
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("EditingCustom_Read", "MyUser"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("EditingCustom_Create", "MyUser"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingCustom_Update", "MyUser"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingCustom_Destroy", "MyUser"))
  )
)


  <script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "Errors:\n";
        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if ('errors' in value) {
                $.each(value.errors, function() {
                    message += this + "\n";
                });
            }
        });
        alert(message);
    }
}
</script>
<script>
  OrderDetails_Error = function (args) {
    if (args.errors) {
        var grid = $("#orderDetailsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var validationTemplate = 
     kendo.template($("#orderDetailsValidationMessageTemplate").html());
        grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.each(args.errors, function (propertyName) {
                // take the template and insert it into the placeholder
                var renderedTemplate = validationTemplate({ field: 
    propertyName, messages: this.errors });

   grid.editable.element.find(".errors").append(renderedTemplate);
              });
          });
       }
   };
</script>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" 
 id="orderDetailsValidationMessageTemplate">
  # if (messages.length) { #
    <li>#=field#
        <ul>
            # for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; ++i) { #
                <li>#= messages[i] #</li>
            # } #
        </ul>
     </li>
   # } #
   </script>

  <script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }

   </script>
```

It show all of the data for the first time, but when reload the the information, do not show data in grid!

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in the Controller and stepped through the code that creates the model "UserViewModel" for the view ?  You may have some reliance on TempData that is cleared out by refresh.  Have you looked the browser Developer Tools Network tab for any errors or unexpected status codes pertaining to the ajax calls ?

Comment: That's right,the problem was in service class and i used break point to find it,thanks a lot! @carstenFranke